# Power set of large set

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, powerset

I have to calculate power set of set which may have more elements upto `10^5`. I tried an algo and the code below but it failed (I think cause large value of `pow(2, size)`).

```
void printPowerSet(int *set, int set_size)
{
unsigned int pow_set_size = pow(2, set_size);
int counter, j,sum=0;
 for(counter = 0; counter < pow_set_size; counter++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < set_size; j++)
   {
      if(counter & (1<<j))
     std::cout<<set[i]<<" ";
   }
   std::cout<<sum;
   sum=0;
   printf("\n");
}
}
```

Is there any other algorithm or how can I fix this one (if it is possible)??

**OR**

`Can you suggest me how to do it i.e. finding subset of large set.`

> > As pointed out in an answer it seems I'm stuck in 
> >      [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Basically, I need sum of all subsets of any set. Now if you can suggest me any other approach to solve the problem.
> >     
> >     Thank you.

Comment: "I think cause large value of `pow(2, size)`" - Well, does it work correctly with a small value of `size`??? Don't **conjecture** what the problem is, debug your code, find out **exactly** what the problem is, and if you're still having problems resolving it on your own, then publish it here along with your intermediate conclusions.

Comment: The number of all subsets is ~10^30102. Are you sure you have to calculate all subsets? Seems like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Comment: @barak yes, it works correctly for small `size`.

Comment: And what **did** you see when you **used** a large value of `size` and **debugged** your code step-by-step?

Comment: At what line of code exactly? What were the values of each of the (relevant) variables?

Comment: well `size` was approx `10^4` and say I have stored set as--
       for(int i=1;i<=t;++i)
    {
        cin>>i;
    }
where `t==10^5`

Comment: Try for values between `n = 15 to n = 30` you will get you point of failure, by that i mean the size is growing exponentially, hence it would become impossible to compute.

Comment: Of course it is possible to compute this set. You have to be careful with the implementation, which _will_take a long time---I am willing to bet it won't terminate in your lifetime---,but it will correctly compute the power set eventually.

Comment: As said by @blazs and in my answer it is `not possible` to print the entire power set not in this lifetime not in the next million lifetimes.

Comment: @uSeemSurprised no, I'm not getting the result.

Comment: even though the power set of a set of numbers of size 10^5 is a trillion billion gazillion times bigger than the number of atoms in the universe, i don't that means we shouldn't try to come up with an algorithm to compute it. I just means we can't store the set and we need to be careful about buffer sizes and recursion depth.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm which will print out the power set of any set that will fit in your computer's memory.

Given enough time, it will print the power set of a set of length 10^5.

However, "enough time" will be something like several trillion billion gazillion years.

c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

void printPowerset (const vector<int>& original_set)
{
    auto print_set = [&original_set](auto first, auto last) -> ostream&
    {
        cout << '(';
        auto sep = "";
        for ( ; first != last  ; ++first, sep = ",")
        {
            cout << sep << original_set[(*first) - 1];
        }
        return cout << ')';
    };

    const int n = original_set.size();
    std::vector<int> index_stack(n + 1, 0);
    int k = 0;


    while(1){
        if (index_stack[k]<n){
            index_stack[k+1] = index_stack[k] + 1;
            k++;
        }

        else{
            index_stack[k-1]++;
            k--;
        }

        if (k==0)
            break;

        print_set(begin(index_stack) + 1, begin(index_stack) + 1 + k);
    }
    print_set(begin(index_stack), begin(index_stack)) << endl;
}

int main(){

    auto nums = vector<int> { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    printPowerset(nums);

    nums = vector<int> { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 };
    printPowerset(nums);

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

first power set (4 items):

```
(2)(2,4)(2,4,6)(2,4,6,8)(2,4,8)(2,6)(2,6,8)(2,8)(4)(4,6)(4,6,8)(4,8)(6)(6,8)(8)()
```

second power set (10 items)

```
(2)(2,4)(2,4,6)(2,4,6,8)(2,4,6,8,10)(2,4,6,8,10,12)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,20)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,18)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,20)(2,4,6,8,10,12,16)(2,4,6,8,10,12,16,18)(2,4,6,8,10,12,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,12,16,20)(2,4,6,8,10,12,18)(2,4,6,8,10,12,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,12,20)(2,4,6,8,10,14)(2,4,6,8,10,14,16)(2,4,6,8,10,14,16,18)(2,4,6,8,10,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,14,16,20)(2,4,6,8,10,14,18)(2,4,6,8,10,14,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,14,20)(2,4,6,8,10,16)(2,4,6,8,10,16,18)(2,4,6,8,10,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,16,20)(2,4,6,8,10,18)(2,4,6,8,10,18,20)(2,4,6,8,10,20)(2,4,6,8,12)(2,4,6,8,12,14)(2,4,6,8,12,14,16)(2,4,6,8,12,14,16,18)(2,4,6,8,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,12,14,16,20)(2,4,6,8,12,14,18)(2,4,6,8,12,14,18,20)(2,4,6,8,12,14,20)(2,4,6,8,12,16)(2,4,6,8,12,16,18)(2,4,6,8,12,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,12,16,20)(2,4,6,8,12,18)(2,4,6,8,12,18,20)(2,4,6,8,12,20)(2,4,6,8,14)(2,4,6,8,14,16)(2,4,6,8,14,16,18)(2,4,6,8,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,14,16,20)(2,4,6,8,14,18)(2,4,6,8,14,18,20)(2,4,6,8,14,20)(2,4,6,8,16)(2,4,6,8,16,18)(2,4,6,8,16,18,20)(2,4,6,8,16,20)(2,4,6,8,18)(2,4,6,8,18,20)(2,4,6,8,20)(2,4,6,10)(2,4,6,10,12)(2,4,6,10,12,14)(2,4,6,10,12,14,16)(2,4,6,10,12,14,16,18)(2,4,6,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,10,12,14,16,20)(2,4,6,10,12,14,18)(2,4,6,10,12,14,18,20)(2,4,6,10,12,14,20)(2,4,6,10,12,16)(2,4,6,10,12,16,18)(2,4,6,10,12,16,18,20)(2,4,6,10,12,16,20)(2,4,6,10,12,18)(2,4,6,10,12,18,20)(2,4,6,10,12,20)(2,4,6,10,14)(2,4,6,10,14,16)(2,4,6,10,14,16,18)(2,4,6,10,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,10,14,16,20)(2,4,6,10,14,18)(2,4,6,10,14,18,20)(2,4,6,10,14,20)(2,4,6,10,16)(2,4,6,10,16,18)(2,4,6,10,16,18,20)(2,4,6,10,16,20)(2,4,6,10,18)(2,4,6,10,18,20)(2,4,6,10,20)(2,4,6,12)(2,4,6,12,14)(2,4,6,12,14,16)(2,4,6,12,14,16,18)(2,4,6,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,12,14,16,20)(2,4,6,12,14,18)(2,4,6,12,14,18,20)(2,4,6,12,14,20)(2,4,6,12,16)(2,4,6,12,16,18)(2,4,6,12,16,18,20)(2,4,6,12,16,20)(2,4,6,12,18)(2,4,6,12,18,20)(2,4,6,12,20)(2,4,6,14)(2,4,6,14,16)(2,4,6,14,16,18)(2,4,6,14,16,18,20)(2,4,6,14,16,20)(2,4,6,14,18)(2,4,6,14,18,20)(2,4,6,14,20)(2,4,6,16)(2,4,6,16,18)(2,4,6,16,18,20)(2,4,6,16,20)(2,4,6,18)(2,4,6,18,20)(2,4,6,20)(2,4,8)(2,4,8,10)(2,4,8,10,12)(2,4,8,10,12,14)(2,4,8,10,12,14,16)(2,4,8,10,12,14,16,18)(2,4,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,8,10,12,14,16,20)(2,4,8,10,12,14,18)(2,4,8,10,12,14,18,20)(2,4,8,10,12,14,20)(2,4,8,10,12,16)(2,4,8,10,12,16,18)(2,4,8,10,12,16,18,20)(2,4,8,10,12,16,20)(2,4,8,10,12,18)(2,4,8,10,12,18,20)(2,4,8,10,12,20)(2,4,8,10,14)(2,4,8,10,14,16)(2,4,8,10,14,16,18)(2,4,8,10,14,16,18,20)(2,4,8,10,14,16,20)(2,4,8,10,14,18)(2,4,8,10,14,18,20)(2,4,8,10,14,20)(2,4,8,10,16)(2,4,8,10,16,18)(2,4,8,10,16,18,20)(2,4,8,10,16,20)(2,4,8,10,18)(2,4,8,10,18,20)(2,4,8,10,20)(2,4,8,12)(2,4,8,12,14)(2,4,8,12,14,16)(2,4,8,12,14,16,18)(2,4,8,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,8,12,14,16,20)(2,4,8,12,14,18)(2,4,8,12,14,18,20)(2,4,8,12,14,20)(2,4,8,12,16)(2,4,8,12,16,18)(2,4,8,12,16,18,20)(2,4,8,12,16,20)(2,4,8,12,18)(2,4,8,12,18,20)(2,4,8,12,20)(2,4,8,14)(2,4,8,14,16)(2,4,8,14,16,18)(2,4,8,14,16,18,20)(2,4,8,14,16,20)(2,4,8,14,18)(2,4,8,14,18,20)(2,4,8,14,20)(2,4,8,16)(2,4,8,16,18)(2,4,8,16,18,20)(2,4,8,16,20)(2,4,8,18)(2,4,8,18,20)(2,4,8,20)(2,4,10)(2,4,10,12)(2,4,10,12,14)(2,4,10,12,14,16)(2,4,10,12,14,16,18)(2,4,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,10,12,14,16,20)(2,4,10,12,14,18)(2,4,10,12,14,18,20)(2,4,10,12,14,20)(2,4,10,12,16)(2,4,10,12,16,18)(2,4,10,12,16,18,20)(2,4,10,12,16,20)(2,4,10,12,18)(2,4,10,12,18,20)(2,4,10,12,20)(2,4,10,14)(2,4,10,14,16)(2,4,10,14,16,18)(2,4,10,14,16,18,20)(2,4,10,14,16,20)(2,4,10,14,18)(2,4,10,14,18,20)(2,4,10,14,20)(2,4,10,16)(2,4,10,16,18)(2,4,10,16,18,20)(2,4,10,16,20)(2,4,10,18)(2,4,10,18,20)(2,4,10,20)(2,4,12)(2,4,12,14)(2,4,12,14,16)(2,4,12,14,16,18)(2,4,12,14,16,18,20)(2,4,12,14,16,20)(2,4,12,14,18)(2,4,12,14,18,20)(2,4,12,14,20)(2,4,12,16)(2,4,12,16,18)(2,4,12,16,18,20)(2,4,12,16,20)(2,4,12,18)(2,4,12,18,20)(2,4,12,20)(2,4,14)(2,4,14,16)(2,4,14,16,18)(2,4,14,16,18,20)(2,4,14,16,20)(2,4,14,18)(2,4,14,18,20)(2,4,14,20)(2,4,16)(2,4,16,18)(2,4,16,18,20)(2,4,16,20)(2,4,18)(2,4,18,20)(2,4,20)(2,6)(2,6,8)(2,6,8,10)(2,6,8,10,12)(2,6,8,10,12,14)(2,6,8,10,12,14,16)(2,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)(2,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,6,8,10,12,14,16,20)(2,6,8,10,12,14,18)(2,6,8,10,12,14,18,20)(2,6,8,10,12,14,20)(2,6,8,10,12,16)(2,6,8,10,12,16,18)(2,6,8,10,12,16,18,20)(2,6,8,10,12,16,20)(2,6,8,10,12,18)(2,6,8,10,12,18,20)(2,6,8,10,12,20)(2,6,8,10,14)(2,6,8,10,14,16)(2,6,8,10,14,16,18)(2,6,8,10,14,16,18,20)(2,6,8,10,14,16,20)(2,6,8,10,14,18)(2,6,8,10,14,18,20)(2,6,8,10,14,20)(2,6,8,10,16)(2,6,8,10,16,18)(2,6,8,10,16,18,20)(2,6,8,10,16,20)(2,6,8,10,18)(2,6,8,10,18,20)(2,6,8,10,20)(2,6,8,12)(2,6,8,12,14)(2,6,8,12,14,16)(2,6,8,12,14,16,18)(2,6,8,12,14,16,18,20)(2,6,8,12,14,16,20)(2,6,8,12,14,18)(2,6,8,12,14,18,20)(2,6,8,12,14,20)(2,6,8,12,16)(2,6,8,12,16,18)(2,6,8,12,16,18,20)(2,6,8,12,16,20)(2,6,8,12,18)(2,6,8,12,18,20)(2,6,8,12,20)(2,6,8,14)(2,6,8,14,16)(2,6,8,14,16,18)(2,6,8,14,16,18,20)(2,6,8,14,16,20)(2,6,8,14,18)(2,6,8,14,18,20)(2,6,8,14,20)(2,6,8,16)(2,6,8,16,18)(2,6,8,16,18,20)(2,6,8,16,20)(2,6,8,18)(2,6,8,18,20)(2,6,8,20)(2,6,10)(2,6,10,12)(2,6,10,12,14)(2,6,10,12,14,16)(2,6,10,12,14,16,18)(2,6,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,6,10,12,14,16,20)(2,6,10,12,14,18)(2,6,10,12,14,18,20)(2,6,10,12,14,20)(2,6,10,12,16)(2,6,10,12,16,18)(2,6,10,12,16,18,20)(2,6,10,12,16,20)(2,6,10,12,18)(2,6,10,12,18,20)(2,6,10,12,20)(2,6,10,14)(2,6,10,14,16)(2,6,10,14,16,18)(2,6,10,14,16,18,20)(2,6,10,14,16,20)(2,6,10,14,18)(2,6,10,14,18,20)(2,6,10,14,20)(2,6,10,16)(2,6,10,16,18)(2,6,10,16,18,20)(2,6,10,16,20)(2,6,10,18)(2,6,10,18,20)(2,6,10,20)(2,6,12)(2,6,12,14)(2,6,12,14,16)(2,6,12,14,16,18)(2,6,12,14,16,18,20)(2,6,12,14,16,20)(2,6,12,14,18)(2,6,12,14,18,20)(2,6,12,14,20)(2,6,12,16)(2,6,12,16,18)(2,6,12,16,18,20)(2,6,12,16,20)(2,6,12,18)(2,6,12,18,20)(2,6,12,20)(2,6,14)(2,6,14,16)(2,6,14,16,18)(2,6,14,16,18,20)(2,6,14,16,20)(2,6,14,18)(2,6,14,18,20)(2,6,14,20)(2,6,16)(2,6,16,18)(2,6,16,18,20)(2,6,16,20)(2,6,18)(2,6,18,20)(2,6,20)(2,8)(2,8,10)(2,8,10,12)(2,8,10,12,14)(2,8,10,12,14,16)(2,8,10,12,14,16,18)(2,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,8,10,12,14,16,20)(2,8,10,12,14,18)(2,8,10,12,14,18,20)(2,8,10,12,14,20)(2,8,10,12,16)(2,8,10,12,16,18)(2,8,10,12,16,18,20)(2,8,10,12,16,20)(2,8,10,12,18)(2,8,10,12,18,20)(2,8,10,12,20)(2,8,10,14)(2,8,10,14,16)(2,8,10,14,16,18)(2,8,10,14,16,18,20)(2,8,10,14,16,20)(2,8,10,14,18)(2,8,10,14,18,20)(2,8,10,14,20)(2,8,10,16)(2,8,10,16,18)(2,8,10,16,18,20)(2,8,10,16,20)(2,8,10,18)(2,8,10,18,20)(2,8,10,20)(2,8,12)(2,8,12,14)(2,8,12,14,16)(2,8,12,14,16,18)(2,8,12,14,16,18,20)(2,8,12,14,16,20)(2,8,12,14,18)(2,8,12,14,18,20)(2,8,12,14,20)(2,8,12,16)(2,8,12,16,18)(2,8,12,16,18,20)(2,8,12,16,20)(2,8,12,18)(2,8,12,18,20)(2,8,12,20)(2,8,14)(2,8,14,16)(2,8,14,16,18)(2,8,14,16,18,20)(2,8,14,16,20)(2,8,14,18)(2,8,14,18,20)(2,8,14,20)(2,8,16)(2,8,16,18)(2,8,16,18,20)(2,8,16,20)(2,8,18)(2,8,18,20)(2,8,20)(2,10)(2,10,12)(2,10,12,14)(2,10,12,14,16)(2,10,12,14,16,18)(2,10,12,14,16,18,20)(2,10,12,14,16,20)(2,10,12,14,18)(2,10,12,14,18,20)(2,10,12,14,20)(2,10,12,16)(2,10,12,16,18)(2,10,12,16,18,20)(2,10,12,16,20)(2,10,12,18)(2,10,12,18,20)(2,10,12,20)(2,10,14)(2,10,14,16)(2,10,14,16,18)(2,10,14,16,18,20)(2,10,14,16,20)(2,10,14,18)(2,10,14,18,20)(2,10,14,20)(2,10,16)(2,10,16,18)(2,10,16,18,20)(2,10,16,20)(2,10,18)(2,10,18,20)(2,10,20)(2,12)(2,12,14)(2,12,14,16)(2,12,14,16,18)(2,12,14,16,18,20)(2,12,14,16,20)(2,12,14,18)(2,12,14,18,20)(2,12,14,20)(2,12,16)(2,12,16,18)(2,12,16,18,20)(2,12,16,20)(2,12,18)(2,12,18,20)(2,12,20)(2,14)(2,14,16)(2,14,16,18)(2,14,16,18,20)(2,14,16,20)(2,14,18)(2,14,18,20)(2,14,20)(2,16)(2,16,18)(2,16,18,20)(2,16,20)(2,18)(2,18,20)(2,20)(4)(4,6)(4,6,8)(4,6,8,10)(4,6,8,10,12)(4,6,8,10,12,14)(4,6,8,10,12,14,16)(4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)(4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(4,6,8,10,12,14,16,20)(4,6,8,10,12,14,18)(4,6,8,10,12,14,18,20)(4,6,8,10,12,14,20)(4,6,8,10,12,16)(4,6,8,10,12,16,18)(4,6,8,10,12,16,18,20)(4,6,8,10,12,16,20)(4,6,8,10,12,18)(4,6,8,10,12,18,20)(4,6,8,10,12,20)(4,6,8,10,14)(4,6,8,10,14,16)(4,6,8,10,14,16,18)(4,6,8,10,14,16,18,20)(4,6,8,10,14,16,20)(4,6,8,10,14,18)(4,6,8,10,14,18,20)(4,6,8,10,14,20)(4,6,8,10,16)(4,6,8,10,16,18)(4,6,8,10,16,18,20)(4,6,8,10,16,20)(4,6,8,10,18)(4,6,8,10,18,20)(4,6,8,10,20)(4,6,8,12)(4,6,8,12,14)(4,6,8,12,14,16)(4,6,8,12,14,16,18)(4,6,8,12,14,16,18,20)(4,6,8,12,14,16,20)(4,6,8,12,14,18)(4,6,8,12,14,18,20)(4,6,8,12,14,20)(4,6,8,12,16)(4,6,8,12,16,18)(4,6,8,12,16,18,20)(4,6,8,12,16,20)(4,6,8,12,18)(4,6,8,12,18,20)(4,6,8,12,20)(4,6,8,14)(4,6,8,14,16)(4,6,8,14,16,18)(4,6,8,14,16,18,20)(4,6,8,14,16,20)(4,6,8,14,18)(4,6,8,14,18,20)(4,6,8,14,20)(4,6,8,16)(4,6,8,16,18)(4,6,8,16,18,20)(4,6,8,16,20)(4,6,8,18)(4,6,8,18,20)(4,6,8,20)(4,6,10)(4,6,10,12)(4,6,10,12,14)(4,6,10,12,14,16)(4,6,10,12,14,16,18)(4,6,10,12,14,16,18,20)(4,6,10,12,14,16,20)(4,6,10,12,14,18)(4,6,10,12,14,18,20)(4,6,10,12,14,20)(4,6,10,12,16)(4,6,10,12,16,18)(4,6,10,12,16,18,20)(4,6,10,12,16,20)(4,6,10,12,18)(4,6,10,12,18,20)(4,6,10,12,20)(4,6,10,14)(4,6,10,14,16)(4,6,10,14,16,18)(4,6,10,14,16,18,20)(4,6,10,14,16,20)(4,6,10,14,18)(4,6,10,14,18,20)(4,6,10,14,20)(4,6,10,16)(4,6,10,16,18)(4,6,10,16,18,20)(4,6,10,16,20)(4,6,10,18)(4,6,10,18,20)(4,6,10,20)(4,6,12)(4,6,12,14)(4,6,12,14,16)(4,6,12,14,16,18)(4,6,12,14,16,18,20)(4,6,12,14,16,20)(4,6,12,14,18)(4,6,12,14,18,20)(4,6,12,14,20)(4,6,12,16)(4,6,12,16,18)(4,6,12,16,18,20)(4,6,12,16,20)(4,6,12,18)(4,6,12,18,20)(4,6,12,20)(4,6,14)(4,6,14,16)(4,6,14,16,18)(4,6,14,16,18,20)(4,6,14,16,20)(4,6,14,18)(4,6,14,18,20)(4,6,14,20)(4,6,16)(4,6,16,18)(4,6,16,18,20)(4,6,16,20)(4,6,18)(4,6,18,20)(4,6,20)(4,8)(4,8,10)(4,8,10,12)(4,8,10,12,14)(4,8,10,12,14,16)(4,8,10,12,14,16,18)(4,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(4,8,10,12,14,16,20)(4,8,10,12,14,18)(4,8,10,12,14,18,20)(4,8,10,12,14,20)(4,8,10,12,16)(4,8,10,12,16,18)(4,8,10,12,16,18,20)(4,8,10,12,16,20)(4,8,10,12,18)(4,8,10,12,18,20)(4,8,10,12,20)(4,8,10,14)(4,8,10,14,16)(4,8,10,14,16,18)(4,8,10,14,16,18,20)(4,8,10,14,16,20)(4,8,10,14,18)(4,8,10,14,18,20)(4,8,10,14,20)(4,8,10,16)(4,8,10,16,18)(4,8,10,16,18,20)(4,8,10,16,20)(4,8,10,18)(4,8,10,18,20)(4,8,10,20)(4,8,12)(4,8,12,14)(4,8,12,14,16)(4,8,12,14,16,18)(4,8,12,14,16,18,20)(4,8,12,14,16,20)(4,8,12,14,18)(4,8,12,14,18,20)(4,8,12,14,20)(4,8,12,16)(4,8,12,16,18)(4,8,12,16,18,20)(4,8,12,16,20)(4,8,12,18)(4,8,12,18,20)(4,8,12,20)(4,8,14)(4,8,14,16)(4,8,14,16,18)(4,8,14,16,18,20)(4,8,14,16,20)(4,8,14,18)(4,8,14,18,20)(4,8,14,20)(4,8,16)(4,8,16,18)(4,8,16,18,20)(4,8,16,20)(4,8,18)(4,8,18,20)(4,8,20)(4,10)(4,10,12)(4,10,12,14)(4,10,12,14,16)(4,10,12,14,16,18)(4,10,12,14,16,18,20)(4,10,12,14,16,20)(4,10,12,14,18)(4,10,12,14,18,20)(4,10,12,14,20)(4,10,12,16)(4,10,12,16,18)(4,10,12,16,18,20)(4,10,12,16,20)(4,10,12,18)(4,10,12,18,20)(4,10,12,20)(4,10,14)(4,10,14,16)(4,10,14,16,18)(4,10,14,16,18,20)(4,10,14,16,20)(4,10,14,18)(4,10,14,18,20)(4,10,14,20)(4,10,16)(4,10,16,18)(4,10,16,18,20)(4,10,16,20)(4,10,18)(4,10,18,20)(4,10,20)(4,12)(4,12,14)(4,12,14,16)(4,12,14,16,18)(4,12,14,16,18,20)(4,12,14,16,20)(4,12,14,18)(4,12,14,18,20)(4,12,14,20)(4,12,16)(4,12,16,18)(4,12,16,18,20)(4,12,16,20)(4,12,18)(4,12,18,20)(4,12,20)(4,14)(4,14,16)(4,14,16,18)(4,14,16,18,20)(4,14,16,20)(4,14,18)(4,14,18,20)(4,14,20)(4,16)(4,16,18)(4,16,18,20)(4,16,20)(4,18)(4,18,20)(4,20)(6)(6,8)(6,8,10)(6,8,10,12)(6,8,10,12,14)(6,8,10,12,14,16)(6,8,10,12,14,16,18)(6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(6,8,10,12,14,16,20)(6,8,10,12,14,18)(6,8,10,12,14,18,20)(6,8,10,12,14,20)(6,8,10,12,16)(6,8,10,12,16,18)(6,8,10,12,16,18,20)(6,8,10,12,16,20)(6,8,10,12,18)(6,8,10,12,18,20)(6,8,10,12,20)(6,8,10,14)(6,8,10,14,16)(6,8,10,14,16,18)(6,8,10,14,16,18,20)(6,8,10,14,16,20)(6,8,10,14,18)(6,8,10,14,18,20)(6,8,10,14,20)(6,8,10,16)(6,8,10,16,18)(6,8,10,16,18,20)(6,8,10,16,20)(6,8,10,18)(6,8,10,18,20)(6,8,10,20)(6,8,12)(6,8,12,14)(6,8,12,14,16)(6,8,12,14,16,18)(6,8,12,14,16,18,20)(6,8,12,14,16,20)(6,8,12,14,18)(6,8,12,14,18,20)(6,8,12,14,20)(6,8,12,16)(6,8,12,16,18)(6,8,12,16,18,20)(6,8,12,16,20)(6,8,12,18)(6,8,12,18,20)(6,8,12,20)(6,8,14)(6,8,14,16)(6,8,14,16,18)(6,8,14,16,18,20)(6,8,14,16,20)(6,8,14,18)(6,8,14,18,20)(6,8,14,20)(6,8,16)(6,8,16,18)(6,8,16,18,20)(6,8,16,20)(6,8,18)(6,8,18,20)(6,8,20)(6,10)(6,10,12)(6,10,12,14)(6,10,12,14,16)(6,10,12,14,16,18)(6,10,12,14,16,18,20)(6,10,12,14,16,20)(6,10,12,14,18)(6,10,12,14,18,20)(6,10,12,14,20)(6,10,12,16)(6,10,12,16,18)(6,10,12,16,18,20)(6,10,12,16,20)(6,10,12,18)(6,10,12,18,20)(6,10,12,20)(6,10,14)(6,10,14,16)(6,10,14,16,18)(6,10,14,16,18,20)(6,10,14,16,20)(6,10,14,18)(6,10,14,18,20)(6,10,14,20)(6,10,16)(6,10,16,18)(6,10,16,18,20)(6,10,16,20)(6,10,18)(6,10,18,20)(6,10,20)(6,12)(6,12,14)(6,12,14,16)(6,12,14,16,18)(6,12,14,16,18,20)(6,12,14,16,20)(6,12,14,18)(6,12,14,18,20)(6,12,14,20)(6,12,16)(6,12,16,18)(6,12,16,18,20)(6,12,16,20)(6,12,18)(6,12,18,20)(6,12,20)(6,14)(6,14,16)(6,14,16,18)(6,14,16,18,20)(6,14,16,20)(6,14,18)(6,14,18,20)(6,14,20)(6,16)(6,16,18)(6,16,18,20)(6,16,20)(6,18)(6,18,20)(6,20)(8)(8,10)(8,10,12)(8,10,12,14)(8,10,12,14,16)(8,10,12,14,16,18)(8,10,12,14,16,18,20)(8,10,12,14,16,20)(8,10,12,14,18)(8,10,12,14,18,20)(8,10,12,14,20)(8,10,12,16)(8,10,12,16,18)(8,10,12,16,18,20)(8,10,12,16,20)(8,10,12,18)(8,10,12,18,20)(8,10,12,20)(8,10,14)(8,10,14,16)(8,10,14,16,18)(8,10,14,16,18,20)(8,10,14,16,20)(8,10,14,18)(8,10,14,18,20)(8,10,14,20)(8,10,16)(8,10,16,18)(8,10,16,18,20)(8,10,16,20)(8,10,18)(8,10,18,20)(8,10,20)(8,12)(8,12,14)(8,12,14,16)(8,12,14,16,18)(8,12,14,16,18,20)(8,12,14,16,20)(8,12,14,18)(8,12,14,18,20)(8,12,14,20)(8,12,16)(8,12,16,18)(8,12,16,18,20)(8,12,16,20)(8,12,18)(8,12,18,20)(8,12,20)(8,14)(8,14,16)(8,14,16,18)(8,14,16,18,20)(8,14,16,20)(8,14,18)(8,14,18,20)(8,14,20)(8,16)(8,16,18)(8,16,18,20)(8,16,20)(8,18)(8,18,20)(8,20)(10)(10,12)(10,12,14)(10,12,14,16)(10,12,14,16,18)(10,12,14,16,18,20)(10,12,14,16,20)(10,12,14,18)(10,12,14,18,20)(10,12,14,20)(10,12,16)(10,12,16,18)(10,12,16,18,20)(10,12,16,20)(10,12,18)(10,12,18,20)(10,12,20)(10,14)(10,14,16)(10,14,16,18)(10,14,16,18,20)(10,14,16,20)(10,14,18)(10,14,18,20)(10,14,20)(10,16)(10,16,18)(10,16,18,20)(10,16,20)(10,18)(10,18,20)(10,20)(12)(12,14)(12,14,16)(12,14,16,18)(12,14,16,18,20)(12,14,16,20)(12,14,18)(12,14,18,20)(12,14,20)(12,16)(12,16,18)(12,16,18,20)(12,16,20)(12,18)(12,18,20)(12,20)(14)(14,16)(14,16,18)(14,16,18,20)(14,16,20)(14,18)(14,18,20)(14,20)(16)(16,18)(16,18,20)(16,20)(18)(18,20)(20)()
```

Comment: Very nice. :-) Which algorithm are you using?

Comment: @blazs I have no idea if it even has a name. If there is a formal algorithm for this I'd like to know. I have no formal mathematical training.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, as you pointed out yourself power set contains `pow(2, size)` no of elements. You need to print the entire set that can only be done by generating the set using `backtracking`, there is nothing better.

---

To find sum of all subsets of a given set is however a simpler problem.

If the no of elements is n, then each element in the array occurs `2^(n-1)` times in the power set.

Pseudo code :

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
    sum += ( set[i] * ( 1 << (n-1) ) );    //pow(2, n-1) == 1 << (n-1)
}

cout << sum << endl;
```

You would need a `Big Integer Library` for larger values of `n`.

Comment: I disagree sir. I have posted a solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since number of elements in the set can go upto `10^5` and hence the size of the set will go upto `2^(10^5)` which is huge. You can just either print it or if you want to store it , store it in a file.

Comment: `2^(10^5)` has 30103 decimal digits : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2**100000 . It is not possible to store it or print it.

Comment: Printing it means ... the power set of the set.

Comment: what do you mean by that?? It would not be possible to store or print all the elements of a power set if `n = 50`, let alone for `n = 10^5`.

Comment: for comparison, there are only 10^80 atoms in the universe :-)